# How to set Main Inerface in xCode programatically

Tags: xcode

I am using Apples MultipleDetailViews http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MultipleDetailViews/Introduction/Intro.html
for template as a source for my iPad app. The template is using a splitviewController in the interface builder (MainWindow). In the iPhone/iPad Deployment info of the target, MainWindow is set as the "Main Interface".

I want my app to also run on iPhone. This means I need to load a different xib when the app is run on an iPhone. I must then remove "MainWindow" from "Main Interface" because the app will crash when I load on an iPhone due to the splitViewController.

The AppDeleagte of the template look like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];        self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

If I remove "Main Window" from "Main Interface", how do I then need to change the APpDelegate, or maybe I need to change the MainWindow.xib to also work for iPhone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself, and I am ashamed about how simple it really was. There is one "Main Interface" for iPhone, and one for iPad :-S.  All this messing around for nothing :-(